# Is there a way to open a second workspace on the visual studio code GUI?

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-code, gui

I only use VSCode for text editing and formatting not really tasking advantages of the actual workspace architectures as much as I should. So I know its not meant for that or I can add just multiple folders but is there a way to actually have 2 different workspace open at the same time?

Comment: Would multiple files from different workspace work? I don't see any limit on the number of files you can have open (until the tabs get too small to be useful I guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot.

You can open multiple folders in a single workspace, but you can only have one workspace open at a time in a given VS Code window.

A bug report for this from 2 years ago was closed: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43188